# QMutableStringListIterator's QStringList "not a type"?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QMutableStringListIterator` that I want to use to iterate through a `QStringList`, but I keep getting an error in the `.h` file that says my `QStringList` is not a type. Why?

**myClass.h**

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <QDockWidget>
#include <QList>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QMutableStringListIterator>

namespace Ui {
class MyClass;
}

class MyClass: public QDockWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit MyClass(QWidget* parent = 0);
  void someFunc(QString message);
  ~MyClass();

private:
  Ui::Messages* ui;
  QStringList myList;
  QMutableStringListIterator iterator(myList); // it errors here. "myList is not a type"
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
#include "myclass.h"
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QCoreApplication>

MyClass::MyClass(QWidget* parent) :
  QDockWidget(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MyClass),
  iterator(myList)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
  delete ui;
}

void MyClass::someFunc(QString message) {

  myList.append(message);
  qDebug() << myList.length();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. Here's what the `.h` file should look like:

```
private:
  Ui::Messages* ui;
  QStringList myList;
  QMutableStringListIterator iterator; // do not give it the myList here
};
```